# How to resolve a 'BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::getParameter does not exist' exception in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel-5.4

Good afternoon, updated my Laravel 5.4 project from 5.3 and I get the following error

> BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::getParameter
>   does not exist.
>
> Application frames (2) All frames (27) 26 BadMethodCallException
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php102
>   25 Illuminate\Routing\Route __call
>   …/app/Http/Controllers/BaseControllerTrait.php103 24
>   App\Http\Controllers\Core\BaseController __construct [internal]0 23
>   ReflectionClass newInstanceArgs
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php823
>   22 Illuminate\Container\Container build
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php667
>   21 Illuminate\Container\Container resolve
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php615
>   20 Illuminate\Container\Container make
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php767
>   19 Illuminate\Foundation\Application make
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php233 18
>   Illuminate\Routing\Route getController
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php833 17
>   Illuminate\Routing\Route controllerMiddleware
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php794 16
>   Illuminate\Routing\Route gatherMiddleware
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php693 15
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router gatherRouteMiddleware
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php673 14
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router runRouteWithinStack
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php657 13
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router runRoute
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php623 12
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatchToRoute
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php612 11
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router dispatch
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php176
>   10 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php30 9
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php65
>   8 Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\InjectDebugbar handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php163 7
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 6
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php62
>   5 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode handle
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php163 4
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53 3
>   Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing{closure}
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php104 2
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline then
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php151
>   1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel sendRequestThroughRouter
>   …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php116
>   0 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel handle …/public/index.php53

[See a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ1tq.jpg)

Could you please advise me how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

`Illuminate\Routing\Route::getParameter()` public method has been removed in Laravel 5.4, use `parameter()` method instead. Read more [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17550).

Comment: If I read that, but there is no guide or explanation of how to make the change or where.

Comment: @Isa did you use `$request->route()->getParameter('...');` in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `$request->route()->getParameter('...');` which was removed in Laravel 5.4

- Laravel Version: 5.4.2
- PHP Version: N/A
- Database Driver & Version: N/A

**Description:**

Illuminate\Routing\Route::getParameter() public method was removed. Use parameter() method instead.

Read this [merged](https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/3038) pull request

Comment: I solved it by modifying my BaseControllerTrait.php file in the folder / app / http / controllers, removing the get and leaving only Parameter the line
$site = \Route::current()->Parameter('site');

   if($site)
   {
    $site = \Route::current()->Parameter('site');

Comment: yes, exactly. getParameter was migrated to parameter()

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying my BaseControllerTrait.php file in the folder 
/app/http/controllers, removing the get and leaving only Parameter the line

$site = \Route::current()->Parameter('site');

```
        if($site)
        {
            $site = \Route::current()->Parameter('site');
```